# Protected Banner at bottom of Thread

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, specific-question

I noticed that the Protection Banner is at the bottom of this post

[How can I shower without a towel?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/8073/how-can-i-shower-without-a-towel)

It appears it is only me.  [@Michaelpri said that it is correct for him in Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/23864166#23864166)

> @Malachi I see it right under the question and before the comments. Is it not like that for you?

I am currently using Chrome `Version 44.0.2403.157 m`

[image: Bug image from question]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)

On [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202366/eeeek-something-stole-the-protection-why-is-this-protected-question-unprotect), we see that users that haven't heard 10 reputation on a site (this does not include the association bonus) see the protected banner at the bottom of the question where the Answer Question button would be.

If you have earned 10 reputation, you will see the banner just above the comments on the question.